# Collision detection with Octomap

Tags: ros, octomap, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all:

I am recently introduced in Octomap. I am trying to implementa motion planner but I need two things:

- given the robot shape and its pose, check if there is a collision given an stored octree
- given the robot shape and its pose, retrieve the nearest obstacle in the octree

¿Is there anything implemented that I can use?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/161476/collision-detection-with-octomap/) by [AdrianGonzalez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12721/adriangonzalez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2014-05-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Collision checking based on OctoMap is already implemented in the arm_navigation stack or better in its successor MoveIt, so the simplest thing would be to use that for collision checks. As an alternative you will have to iterate over the occupied voxels of OctoMap (best in a local bounding box) and see if they intersect with the robot.

Distance queries based on an existing OctoMap can be answered with the dynamicEDT3D library, which is distributed along with the source of OctoMap (although not yet released in ROS).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-05-05**:
+1 for using the MoveIt framework to implement a motion planner.

**Comment by [AdrianGonzalez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12721/adriangonzalez/) on 2014-05-13**:
thank you @AHornung. For my problem, I finally will require to iterate over a local bounding box over the occupied voxels, because I need to weight all the obstacles in a region around the robot according to several parameters of my application. Thank you for your response.